# using SRCROOT in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use [`SRCROOT`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW106) path in my project like so:

```
// Create NSTask to interact with console
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

// Set path to script
NSString *launch_path = @"$SRCROOT/Scripts/my_script.rb";
NSLog(launch_path);
[task setLaunchPath:launch_path];
```

I end up with (in log):

```
$SRCROOT/Scripts/my_script.rb
```

I want to end up to a path inside my project's directory like this:

```
/Application/Scripts/my_script.rb
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

*Additionally, I've tried the following without success:*

```
..
// Set path to script
NSString *launch_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Scripts/auto_checkin.rb", "$SRCROOT"];
NSLog(launch_path);
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$SRCROOT is meaningless for runtime environment.

If you want to access the document in bundle, make sure the my_script.rb is added in the "Copy Bundle Resources", then try this:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] ;
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_script.rb"] ;
```

[image]

$SRCROOT is path to the project file(*.xcodeproj) that defines the target. link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38)
[image]

The bundle term here represent Application bundle, the application bundle stores everything that the application requires for successful operation. link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1)

Comment: is 'bundle' the proper term for "everything in your project's directory"?

Comment: it may be meaningless for iOS. But I need to access to the sources folder without of writing the path manually